# trying to write code that takes a list and returns a table of the length of the word/ frequency of words that length

Tags: python

Hi i am trying to write code that takes a list and returns a table of the length of the word/ frequency but im not really sure how to do it.

This is my code so far but it doesnt work.
any help on how to restructure it/make it work is much appreciated

```
def table_frequency(new_list):
word_frequency = {}
max_word = len(max(new_list, key=len))

for i in range(1, max_word+1):
    word_frequency[i] = 0

for word in new_list:
    if len(word) in word_frequency:
        word_frequency[len(word)] += 1
    else:
        word_frequency[len(word)] = 1

word_list = max(word_frequency.items(), key=(lambda x: x[0]))
print("\n Len  Freq")
for length, freq in word_list:
    print("{0:>4} {1:>4}".format(length, freq))
```

[correct table output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjN4w.png)
any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: _This is my code so far but it doesnt work_ This doesn't tell us much.  What is it doing, and how is that different from what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is correct, but you are printing the wrong thing.

`word_frequency` is storing your word lengths and frequencies, so your last for loop should print that (NOT `word_list`)

```
for length, freq in word_frequency.items():
    print("{0:>4} {1:>4}".format(length, freq))
```

But if you wanted to use `word_list` itself, make `word_list` have the key value pairs from the dictionary

```
word_list=[[k,v] for k,v in word_frequency.items()]
print("\n Len  Freq")
for length, freq in word_list:
    print("{0:>4} {1:>4}".format(length, freq))
```

Also note that you do not require this for loop :

```
for i in range(1, max_word+1):
    word_frequency[i] = 0
```

Because you are automatically adding each length to the dictionary when you say `word_frequency[len(word)] = 1` in the next for loop

Comment: Thank you so much but now i have a new problem as stated above is the output i want to achieve but when i run the code i only get len : 1 and freq:125 which is obviously wrong. Any ideas? would be much appreciated :)

Comment: @NishanthRodricks Please read my answer carefully. Notice how I have changed `word_list`